# Creating a DNS request in PHP

Tags: php, dns, packet

I'm trying to write a function to create a DNS request and then send it to the DNS server through a socket. I only added relavant parts of the code.

This works:

```
$domain1 = 'example';
$domain2 = 'com';

$data = "\7{$domain1}\3{$domain2}";
```

Now the question is how do I create the $data so that the string lengths are not hardcoded. 
Something similar to this (which does not work):

```
$domain = "example.com";
$bits = explode(".", $domain);
$data = '';
foreach ($bits as $bit) {
     $strlen = strlen($bit);
     $data .= decoct($strlen) . $bit;
}
```

I hope I explaned it correctly as I'm not really sure how it works.

Comment: As I am not familiar with DNS requests, I would ask what is `6` and `3`, because it's definetely not the string length? Example is 7 chars long and as well your function produces the string without the backslashes.

Comment: My bad, it should be 7 and 3. Sorry

Comment: So just add the backslashes and it will be the same

Comment: The answer by Dho below will help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely need the [pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function. This function allows one to easily represent binary data packed into a PHP string. Assuming the lengths are 1 byte each (I think they are):

```
$sld = "example";
$tld = "com";
$packed = pack("Ca*Ca*", strlen($sld), $sld, strlen($tld), $tld);
```

Take a look at the various format characters to make sure this is what you need.

Comment: What is the expected output of this one?

Comment: Thanks. Missing *s in format string. Expected output is effectively "\x07example\x03com".